# Manga where the main character got into an appraisal ritual and became the first mage and got a second soul

Tags: story-identification, manga, isekai

I am looking for an isekai manga (maybe a light novel) where the main character goes for appraisal and becomes the first magician in the world. He accidentally got a second soul and is trying to hide this fact, as usually, those people who hear additional voices become aggressive and start a rampage. In this world, your job is determined by the appraisal. So people usually get something like doctor, priest, mathematician.

**Edit** (more info):

**Ritual**: The appraisal ritual is happening at a specific age for everyone. It is happening in the church on a pedestal with a special pattern on it. Once done you are assigned an occupation based on an animated character that appeared above you at the time of the ritual. After the ritual, the person appraised got all the knowledge necessary for the job (like farmer or doctor)

**Soul**: After the ritual, the boy starts hearing voices and later that night he figures out that the voice belongs to the second soul in his body. The soul is from the earth and belongs to the student. They both occupy the same body.

**Story**: After the strange appraisal as it did something the priest doesn't know start hearing a voice he was scared that he will be tagged as a "mad one" and thus try to lie to the priest. The second voice tells him to claim to be a mathematician. Later that night he got tested and the souls keeps answering all the questions. One of them is based on a programming language that shouldn't be known in this world. It turns out that it was a trick question. As the programming language is linked to god.

Comment: Can you elaborate on the appraisal ritual? Or what happens with the second soul? The Lone Spellcaster has some similarities, depending on how "second soul" is supposed to work. But no ritual. And most people aren't doctors/etc.

Comment: @qazmlpok I updated the post with more informations

Comment: Was this in black&white or full color? Do you have any idea when you read this?

Comment: I read it about 2 years ago. Not sure if it was manga or just WebNovel. That is the main reason I want to find it. If it was manga it would be black and white.